# DMZ an additional router

Tags: network, router, dmz

Recently I had an idea to test use a server (with ubuntu) and I need it to be accessible from the outside with port forwarding.

I'm not often at home, but the internet provider doesn't like their customers to mess around with their routers. Because of that, they change their passwords daily.

I can access the router because I have a "friend" that can give me the access, but I don't want to bother him every time I want to make a change.

I was thinking on setting up an additional router, DMZ its static IP, and from my personal router, open the ports I need.

Is this a good or bad idea?

Comment: Depending upon details, it may be cleaner, easier, and safer to test the idea via an Amazon cloud server. It can be cheap to free at a small scale.

Comment: Well im not from the us, and also im still testing, I dont even bought a server, am just using my old rig with ubuntu server installed for testing.

Answer (score 2):

When you can configure the ISP router to run in bridge mode and connect a second router behind the ISP one, you can manage all your port forwarding rules yourself.

Make sure that DHCP is disabled on the ISP router and enabled on your own router. This might be done automatically when the ISP router is put in bridge mode.

> Is this a good or bad idea?

This depends on how you configure your own router. Exposing the administrative interface over the internet for example is something you probably don't want to do. You are required to manage your own router, check for firmware updates etc.

Additionally, it might (or might not) violate your ISP's policies. Your "friend" most likely is violating his employer's policies.

Since your ISP limits you in exposing external services, you might want to consider changing to another ISP that does not limit you.

Comment: I managed a little bit my own router, changed the access password, updated the firewall to the latest and activated the firewall both on the router and the so called server. And also changing ISP is not much of an option as it is the only company that arrives at my home (at least with good speeds).  
And about the DHCP, why is it recommended to deactivated the ISP routers DHCP? I just want to have access to full port fowarding within my router to test my server so I dont want involve my other ISP network with my testing, I dont really have a problem with it, I just want to bypass its rules.

Comment: In bridge mode, the ISP router is transparent and will send all traffic to your own router. It is quite likely that DHCP on the ISP router is not enabled when in bridge mode, but it was more a suggested precaution you should take in order to avoid having two DHCP servers serve IP addresses to the LAN.